# depmod: ERROR: fstatat No such file or directory

Tags: kernel

Struggled with situation, when I executed command 
`ln -sf  /lib/modules/$kernel_version/extra/mISDN_core.ko /lib/modules/$kernel_version/kernel/drivers/isdn/mISDN/mISDN_core.ko`
then executed `ldconfig`and after that `depmod -a` system provide me an error 
`depmod: ERROR: fstatat(7, mISDN_core.ko): No such file or directory`
what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: thanks to one dude I realized I have named my dir as $user instead of just user ) thanks to all who was breaking heads of the walls

Comment: still having same problem. does anyone knows what is wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: u have created the symbolic-link in lib/modules ,first see whether this file is there in the original location this may cause the problem